# Remove Time From Datetime in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using c#. I have a problem i am unable to remove the time format from datetime variable .
Here is my code.

```
 string Date = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["serviceDate"].ToString();
string ServiceDate = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Date);
```

How to remove the time from this format?

Comment: I assume the column "serviceDate" is already a DateTime-object, why do you want to convert it to string? Just use it as DateTime as it is.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about the _content_ of the DateTime variable, or the _display_ of it?  Do you want to throw away the time component, or just not show it on the screen?

Comment: You can't remove the "Time Format" from a `DateTime`. A `DateTime` doesn't have a format. You can only remove the "Time" from a `DateTime` with a call to the `.Date` property.

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve] to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call the [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property on your `DateTime`.

It gives you a DateTime with the same date, but with the time set to midnight.

Answer (score 0):

By converting the Date into DateTime it will work fine.

```
 DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["serviceDate"]);
 string serviceDate = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", date);
```

Or if your serviceDate Field is already a Datetime then you can try this.

```
string ServiceDate = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["serviceDate"]);
```

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on `DateTime` to call `Convert.ToDateTime()` afterwards does not make any sense ...

Comment: This a is a terrible solution. It sounds like `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["serviceDate"]` is already a `DateTime`. This is why we need a [mcve] from the OP.

Comment: Yes you are right . Thanks for your suggestion.